# RCP with RabbitMQ connected to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

We're currently in the process of connecting our system to elasticsearch. The idea is to push our data to a broker (RabbitMQ), which then transfers it to elasticsearch.

Since rivers have been deprecated in the newest elasticsearch, the only alternative I coud find was using logstash between the broker and elasticsearch.

It works something like this:

> Own System --> RabbitMQ --> Logstash --> elasticsearch

I could successfully connect all the systems, but we have some requests that need to wait for a successful response before they can continue. I found that RCP of RabbitMQ is exactly what I needed, since I can wait until I get the response from the consumer before I continue.

My problem is that I couldn't find anywhere how to configure logstash to use a callback queue.

Is there a way for logstash to use RCP? Or is there an alternative for getting data into elasticsearch with the help of a broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits a queue broker provides is the ability to decouple your system and take advantage of asynchronous processing.  If your system really does require synchronous acknowledgement that a record was successfully inserted into ElasticSearch it may be better to just have your application call the ElasticSearch API directly.  Otherwise your application should be able to handle the failure if data is delayed at being inserted into ElasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is exactly what I figured as well. Why make it complicated if there is a direct route?